Redis RAM usage grows when NestJS app is running
My app only uses Redis for caching few keys, totall size is not so big. When app is not running Redis still keeps old keys so I can verify that it uses only 0.4% of awailable RAM.
RAM usage when app is not running
App does not adding new keys, theirs size are always same. App is just updating existing keys.
But when I'm starting app, it start overflowing RAM and app crashes. When app exits, RAM usage slows down to the beginning size.
RAM usage after 30 seconds app started
I can't understand why it's working like that. Redis keys and size are not changing, connecting instance also same because I'm using DI to provide same factory instance to all app modules.
Redis Factory
Any ideas? This is the last trouble I need to fix but I can't handle it for a long time.

Could it be because of the KeepAlive time of 1 millisecond?

Well, I tried also without it so no. I found that Redis has something called "omem": output buffer memory usage. This buffer rise each time client reads by key. In my case reading is performing about 5 times per socond so this buffer owerflows. Why it's not cleans idk.
